# Java Jbutton непонятные полоски

Tags: java

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть jbutton, при выделении окна программы на кнопке появляются непонятые полоски, как их убрать? 
и можно ли убрать подсвечивание при наведении на кнопку?
код кнопки:

```
    JButton btnStart = new JButton("");

    btnStart.setIcon(new 
    ImageIcon(gui.class.getResource("/AC/drop_logo2.png")));
    btnStart.setBounds(101, 57, 94, 73);

    btnStart.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    frmAnticheat.getContentPane().add(btnStart);
```

Comment: Вероятнее всего размер изображения не совпадает с размером кнопки и вам показываются рамки изображения

Comment: да, в этом и было дело) уже решил) спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Решил вопрос. если кому понадобится

```
    btnStart.setFocusable(false);
    btnStart.setBorderPainted(false);
```